# Burninate "size"

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed the [size](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/size) tag on a question and discovered there are 42 other questions with it. Surely this is a meta tag and needs to go bye bye. If you disagree I'd be interested in the reasons.

Comment: Add the "move" tag to that list.

Comment: Add the "devops" tag to the list too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added [size](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/size), [move](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/move) and [devops](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/devops) to the [bad tag list](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3042/the-bad-tag-collection) so they can all be dealt with together.

Comment: I disagree about [tag:devops].  With the rise of cloud computing and dynamically allocated computing resources, I think devops is a field ripe for an explosion in usage and, of course, questions?

Comment: devops would be a meta tag just like it,system-administration,servers etc and as such is of no real value when you consider the [intended purpose](http://meta.serverfault.com/tags) of tags.

Comment: I don't know what happened to all of the comments and included examples on this thread, but I believe that DevOps, at least in the meaning I intend, would indeed fit the intended purpose of tags. It would distinguish questions about how do I do this once from questions about how do I do this in an automated way that can be automatically repeated ad infinitum.

Comment: I deleted them because they didn't add any value to the discussion about the continued existence of the tag devops. Your comment above just reinforces that you don't understand the purpose of tags in the SF/SE sense.