# Baby light my fire [operating-system]

Tags: discussion

What a crap tag - [operating-system](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/operating-system)

Agreed? If so, let's clean it up over the next few days so we can send it to war on the front line against a battalion of heavilly armed enemy soliders so that it gets killed in battle and then we can marry its wife guilt free. Because adultery is bad, don'tcha know.

Comment: Gotta ask - what is operating-system's wife? If it be `user` she's all yours. I've seen it and it's not very pretty.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't put that much thought into it. It was a distortion of the tale of [David and Bathsheba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathsheba#Biblical_narrative). Only with less seduction.

Answer (score 4):

Agreed; adultery is so much worse than murder.

<sub>There be sarcasm in that statement</sub>

Answer (score 4):

There's also an [os](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/os) tag, at the moment with 48 posts.

Comment: What an ambiguous tag... OS: operating system, open source, open solaris, a backwards acronym for stack overflow...

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by `clean it up` ?

If you mean eradicate then adding it to the [Bad Tag Collection](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3042/the-bad-tag-collection) and as it has 100+ posts probably the section that we'll have to ask the devs to delete.

Otherwise ... ?

Comment: Almost, not not quite. Probably should have been more clear. When I've been retagging them, I've been re-tagging "operating-system" with the actual OS (if mentioned). Doing a mass delete doesn't achieve this unfortunately