# Burninate [repair]?

Tags: discussion, tags

[repair](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/repair) seems like a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) to me (repair what? the RAIDs? the LAMPs? TomTom's phone?). Should it be killed, and if so, how?

Comment: +1 for TomTom's phone... although if it's his phone it might be running LAMP and RAID.

Comment: RAIM: Redundant Array of Inexpensive Mobiles

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- *Does anyone have it Favorited?* **NO**
- *Does the tag mean anything all by its lonesome?* **NO**
- *Is it especially popular?* **NO**

Given that, it should be removed.

I don't think it's worth blacklisting, we only have 34 of 'em after all, but it could definitely go onto [The bad tag collection](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3042/the-bad-tag-collection).

Comment: [Suggested](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3483/115189).