# The "hosts" tag needs some cleanup

Tags: discussion, tags

As it stands the [hosts](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/hosts) tag does not have a tag wiki, and it shows.

Common questions tagged with it include:

- the hosts file (which has a non-aliased cousin [hosts-file](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/hosts-file))
- tcpwrappers (`hosts.{deny,allow}`)
- Newbies typing "virtual host" and spawning two tags. Not that a tag wiki would help with this.

I think it's doomed to pollution no matter what, but it'd be nice if it at least had a tooltip of some sort. It'd provide a pretty butterfly for newbies to ignore when they create questions if nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal take is that [hosts](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/hosts) should refer to the hosts file and that [hosts-file](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/hosts-file) should be aliased to it.

Comment: This seems sensible - there are currently 162 questions tagged with [tag:hosts]. If you untag all the ones that shouldn't have [tag:hosts-file] and let me know I'll create the alias (Otherwise this goes on the pile of "when someone gets around to it" -- that's a [big pile](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3042/the-bad-tag-collection) around here, but it's a relatively small number of questions so it may get done sooner rather than later.